# Road part plane - How can I re-create this in Blender

Tags: mesh, modifiers

Can someone tell me how can I re-create this exact thing in Blender from scratch?

Let's say I want piece like this but 4m wide, with same length and angles.

I saw some tutorials with path and then applying curve modifier, but I need something simple where I could control the exact angles and length.

[image: Road part plane]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)